# java.sql.SQLException: Container 560 not found With Derby

Tags: database, jdbc, derby

I encounter a database exception on Derby.  The error stack is as follows, and the code is at the line "".

Code:

```
    String[] types = { "TABLE", "ALIAS", "SYNONYM" };
    DatabaseMetaData dmeta = null;
    //... 
    //...

    int n = 0;
    String tblName = null;
    try {
        dmeta = connection.getMetaData();
        rs = dmeta.getTables(null, schema, null, types);
```

// this is line DatabaseImpl.java:861
// ~~~~~~~~~ error occur at this method

```
        while (rs.next()) {
            //...
            //...
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        ServiceLogger.logError(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The exception 'java.sql.SQLException: Container 560 not found.' was thrown while evaluating an expression.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.DatabaseMetaData.getTables(Unknown Source)
    at jet.server.db.core.DatabaseImpl.loadTables(DatabaseImpl.java:861)
        ...
        // here, some lines were cut by me.
        ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: The exception 'java.sql.SQLException: Container 560 not found.' was thrown while evaluating an expression.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseEXCSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readExecuteCall(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readExecuteCall(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readExecuteCall_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readExecuteCall(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeQueryX(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.DatabaseMetaData.executeCatalogQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.DatabaseMetaData.getTablesX(Unknown Source)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Container 560 not found.
    ... 42 more
```

After the error, another error is thrown:

```
  java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No current connection.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at jet.server.db.core.ConnectorManager$ConnectionPool$ConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(ConnectorManager.java:888)
at $Proxy5.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
at jet.server.db.adapter.DB.execute(DB.java:758)
at jet.server.db.adapter.DB.createTable(DB.java:784)
...
// ...
...
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
 Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: No current connection.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.checkForClosedConnection(Unknown Source)
... 39 more
```

Comment: Give it a try to `rs = dmeta.getTables(null, null, null, null);` just to see if it works

Comment: The program work well in my lab. And in the customer's lab throw error sometimes. Sometimes, but many times.
I think it is caused by memory overflow, but no evidence.

Comment: After the previous error, another error is throwned.

Comment: Look in your derby.log file on your Derby server. What error message is in that file?